# change display name of cell in sql query output

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query to get results from a table and change the "display names" of the output variables. The query is used for charting and I need to have understandable values to be displayed in the chart. Here is the code that I am using. The last 2 line are the problem. I need to rename the display names.

Appreciate any help

---

```
SELECT table.date, table.concept, table.avg, table.avg90, table.avg30, table.avg7

FROM table
WHERE table.date
IN (

SELECT MAX( DATE ) 
FROM table
GROUP BY table.concept
)
AND table.concept in  ('h2h_globalism','h2h_populism')
WHERE 'h2h_globalism' = 'Globalism')
WHERE 'h2h_populism' = 'Populism')
```

Comment: `select a AS Did, b AS YOU , c AS GOOGLE, d as THIS from TableOfSqlApi`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an alias. For example:

```
SELECT table.date as DATE, table.concept as CONCEPT, table.avg as AVG, table.avg90 as AVG90, table.avg30 as AVG30, table.avg7 as AVG7

FROM table
WHERE table.date
IN (

SELECT MAX( DATE ) 
FROM table
GROUP BY table.concept
)
AND table.concept in  ('h2h_globalism','h2h_populism')
WHERE 'h2h_globalism' = 'Globalism')
WHERE 'h2h_populism' = 'Populism')
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to replace this bit

```
SELECT table.date, table.concept, table.avg, table.avg90, table.avg30, table.avg7
```

With the following.

```
SELECT table.date, 
Case when table.concept = 'h2h_globalism' then 'globalism' else 'populism' end as concept,
 table.avg, table.avg90, table.avg30, table.avg7
```